# What determines the penetration of electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, optical-materials

What is it that determines whether or not an electromagnetic wave can penetrate different materials and how far it can go? For example light can penetrate through glass, but not concrete walls, but radio waves can penetrate concrete walls in large distances

Comment: see “skin depth” with explicit expression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect#Formula

Comment: Do you understand why electric fields cant penetrate a conductor?

Comment: no I didn't know about that